# Difference between “my feet” and “my two feet”

Tags: meaning, differences, sentence-meaning, emphasis

I'm trying to translate the following Prophetic tradition from Arabic to English:

> ألا كل شيء من أمر الجاهلية موضوع تحت قَدَمَيَّ، وربا الجاهلية موضوع كله، وأول ربا أضع ربا العباس بن عبد المطلب.

A literal translation would be:

> Lo! Everything from the affairs of the Period of Ignorance is placed under my two feet. And the usury of the Period of Ignorance – all of it – has been placed (i.e. under my two feet as well) The first usury I place (i.e. under my two feet) is the usury of al-ʿAbbās ibn ʿAbd al-Muṭṭalib.

The problem I see with this is that to *be under my feet* is an English idiom that means something that annoys me. E.g. The children have been under my feet all morning so I haven't been able to get any work done. (Cambridge dictionary of American idioms) However, in Arabic, something placed under the feet is irrelevant, insignificant, and gone to waste.

Thus, a translation of notion would be:

> Lo! Everything from the affairs of the Period of Ignorance has been put down![1] And the usury of the Period of Ignorance — all of it — has been put down! The first usury I put down is the usury of al-ʿAbbās ibn ʿAbd al-Muṭṭalib.

...where “put down” means *to bring to an end*; *disparage*; and *belittle*; it seems appropriate. Arabic has the singular, dual, and plural and the dual for feet is used in the text. Thus:

[1]: lit. is placed under my feet.

[1]: lit. is placed under my two feet.

I want to know the difference between “my feet” and “my two feet” in the aforementioned context.

It is my understanding that “my feet” could mean that it is under one of my two feet, i.e. generally under them, and that “my two feet” means that the thing is completely under *both* of the feet. Is this correct or is “two” just for emphasis? Are there some other differences?

Comment: Neither sounds particularly natural; preceding context would perhaps resolve this. But I'd say including 'two' here is just for the type of emphasis involving 'Would you believe it!?' 'Very' might be a more usual intensifying marker.

Comment: The thing may not have been literally underneath the speaker's feet. "It was right under my feet / nose all along!"

Comment: This is desperately in need of some context.

Comment: What if you're a centipede?

Comment: I suspect it's just for emphasis, as in [stand on one's own two feet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand%20on%20one%27s%20own%20two%20feet#:~:text=Definition%20of%20stand%20on%20one's,on%20your%20own%20two%20feet.).

Comment: Say "I'm standing upon...". Let the reader imagine how many struts you are using.

Comment: The idiom is 'under foot'. "When school is out, the children are always under foot" (meaning annoyingly in the way). 'Under my feet' sounds strange, like they're literally between my feet and the ground.